# Get a network device name

Tags: android, networking, network-programming

I know, from the mac address, how to get the manufacturer information but is there a way to get the device name. I attach a snapshot showing the view from my dsl router. Is it specific to a wifi protocol or is there a generic way to get that info?
I'd like to get the name: bernard-ThinkPad-T420

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I didn't realize the host registers to dns. 
so here is the line of code:

```
String host = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1").getHostName();
```